# Xampp on external drive

Tags: xampp, mac

I have Xampp installed on Mac OSX Version 10.9.2 and all works fine with htdocs and my sql. I would like to be able to run Xampp from my computer but access files on external lacie drive with Firewire 800 (not thunderbolt capable).

How can I do this and if there is a way, can I still access the files on computer as well as the disc or just one with setting?

Appreciate your time.

Cheers, Steve.

Answer (score 1):

You mount the drive as you would any other. This will usually make the files on it available via `/Volumes/Something/` on your local file system.

You can then [specify that location](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html) as a `DocumentRoot` or `Alias` in your Apache configuration.

Alternatively, you can create a symlink to it from somewhere under your existing DocumentRoot (assuming you [enable symlinks](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) in the configuration).